# Transmission rate of vintage Petzval type lenses

Tags: lens, light-transmission

Is anyone aware of a transmission rate test for vintage lenses, such as 1800's Petzval lenses?

Comment: What do you mean by "transmission rate" ? What are the variables in this "test"?   It is not clear what you want to know .  Please add more information in order to help get an informed answer.  **Please take the tour so you understand how to ask questions that are clear and answerable**. https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: See below. I am talking about what is referred to as T-stop, usually in cine lenses.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, loss is generally assumed to be about 4% per glass to air interface in uncoated lenses. So you will have a transmission of 0.96 per interface.

A true petzval lens has six glass to air interfaces and two cemented glass-glass interfaces. Likely, the cemented interfaces do not make a major contribution to loss unless the cement hasd become visibly defective.

So if we take the transmission of 0.96 to the power of six, we get appx. 0.78 - which means an overall light loss of around a half stop. This would often not matter much depending on the film/sensor used, even more if adapted to a camera with internal metering. An externally metered camera should be compensated a half stop slower.

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a reference for the 4% per glass-to-air interface?

Comment: Yes, it is interesting. I am curious because the exposure of wet plates between vintage and modern lenses is quite a lot. For example, some people make 35mm plates, shoot in an SLR using a flash. This is not possible with older cameras/lenses. I'm not sure the exposure difference is explained by the emulsion and so wondered if it was differences between the lens transmission rates.

Comment: @Kahvovius every other whitepaper on optical coatings mentions numbers around 4%.

Answer (score 0):

If the actual SPEED of lenses is the question here, that doesn't only involve transmission, but also practical apertures.

A lens from a time where Petzval lenses were state of the art will be designed for a large format camera of some description. Large format lenses, due to the longer focal lengths needed combined with the requirement of illuminating a large imaging circle, generally are not designed with very fast apertures - though the history information given in marketing literature for some new petzval lenses suggest that f/3.6 at 160mm focal length was possible, which is remarkably fast for a large format lens - though the focal length of 160mm suggests that a plate size was used that, while still large format, was not huge - otherwise 160mm would be too short for portraiture use.
Actually, a f/3.6 lens, combined with the glass losses I discussed in another answer, would be about as "bright" as a typical modern entry level DSLR/DSLM zoom lens.